# Updated Eclipse Juno and all of my android plugins disappeared

Tags: android

The problem I am experiencing is this, I updated my eclipse Juno version and all of my android plugins disappeared. When i try to update it. It does not show in the window tab at all either to make everything show. Can someone please help me and tell me what i have done wrong. I have already tried updating again but it tells me it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me before while updating also. To fix it you need to reinstall the plugins. Here is the link to the official guide on how to do so. http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: I tried your answer and it still did not work it says that all my updates are current but it does not show anything on my eclipse workspace. They are there but will not show any idea why this is?

Comment: Try uninstalling them and then installing them again. To uninstall them you can go to Help>About Eclipse(or about ADT)> Installation Details.

Comment: So I tried uninstalling the plugins and reinstalling them and it still didnt work i didnt want to have to delete reinstall eclipse I appreciate you trying to help me out if you think of anything else let me know.